# How can I not change the matrix

Tags: julia

In Julia, if `t` is some matrix

```
t = [1 2; 3 4]
t1 = t
t1[1,1] = 0
t2 = t
```

`t2` gives out same output as `t1`.

How can I make `t2` to equal `t`?

Answer (score 6):

They are all equal actually:

```
julia> t = [1 2; 3 4]
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2
 3  4

julia> t1 = t
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2
 3  4

julia> t1[1,1] = 0
0

julia> t2 = t
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 0  2
 3  4

julia> t == t1 == t2
true

julia> t === t1 === t2
true

julia> pointer(t), pointer(t1), pointer(t2) # identical
(Ptr{Int64} @0x00007fd213d37000, Ptr{Int64} @0x00007fd213d37000, Ptr{Int64} @0x00007fd213d37000)
```

The variables `t`, `t1`, and `t2` point to the same data, the same memory location. So when you mutate `t1` you mutate all.

If you want them to be different, such that only one is modified, you have to use `copy`:

```
julia> t = [1 2; 3 4];

julia> t1 = copy(t);

julia> t1[1,1] = 0;

julia> t2 = copy(t); # or just t if you want to avoid the copy

julia> t == t1 == t2
false

julia> pointer(t), pointer(t1), pointer(t2)
(Ptr{Int64} @0x00007fd21220e900, Ptr{Int64} @0x00007fd2142f9630, Ptr{Int64} @0x00007fd2142f9a90)
```